# How to extract part of RAW response body (not JSON!) in INSOMNIA Rest Client

Tags: rest, oauth, insomnia

I am using the Insomnia REST client to debug some mobile API. I need to extract **part of one value** in the response body and put it into a second request.

#### Request

The request is an Oauth request for an authorization token. This request is normally sent from a mobile app.

#### Example Response

The backend responds with a redirect_uri that contains the authorization_code. This format is used in oauth when the request (normally in PROD) comes from a mobile app.

```
{
    "redirect_to": "redirect_uri=com.acme://oauth?client_id=abcde&response_type=code&scope=authenticate_user&authorization=H068bFHTXXXXXXXXXXX.....XXXXXXX"
}
```

**How can I extract the value of the authorization parameter from this response in INSOMNIA?**

** How can I extract only the part after "&authorization=....."**

I know how to extract the full value of the "redirect_to" JSON attribute. But then how to parse it? For example with a regex?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to do so, but it is kind of tricky. The most obvious way would be to use some plugin, but here is what I came up with:

Firt of all you need to make a variable which will save your response `redirect_uri=com.acme ...  =authenticate_user&authorization=H068bFHTXXXXXXXXXXX.....XXXXXXX`.

You can do this by pressing:

> CTRL + E

This will open your environment variables, you can really make it in any enviroment, but probably the best would be to do in `Base Enviroment` so it is accessable no matter which environment you are using.

Create a variable like this:
[placeholder variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgIbs.png)

Then you need to get the `redirect_uri` by pressing the following keys between the quotation marks:

> CTRL+SPACE

This will bring up the quick menu, where you can type `Response` and choose body attribute. Click on it, and set it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhReq.png).

I am pretty sure most people are familiar till this point.
Now you have saved the response to a variable you can use it. Navigate to the request where you want to use it, and you can type (basically in any field) `{{ }}`.

Inside this variable write the following (with your own variable name).

`{{ redirect_uri.match('authorization=([^&]+)')[1] }}`

This is basically `javascript`, using a simple `regex` to match the url parameter.

If you did everything correctly [you will see something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2DlC.png), and by clicking on it [you should see your token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zu1L.png).

`Note:` It might be red, until you get some values into the variable that you made.

I really hope it helps.